# How to connect two walls as as T or as a corner

Tags: mesh, modifiers, vertices, snapping

I put all these walls together, snapped their ends to the other faces and merged by distance but I have all these overlapping faces.  I tried to use a boolean tool to remove them or to merge edges but it either deletes the build or claims there are no intersections.  I've already started this over multiple times.  There are two colors now so I can see the intersections and overlap better.  There has got to be an easy way to get these parts to stick together and not have all that overlapping mess inside.  Help!

[image]

Comment: have you tried adding edge loops at the places where the walls intersect, and then joining the vertices at that places?

Comment: Are your the pink and green walls a single mesh or 2 different ones?

Comment: 2 different ones.  I made multiple horizontal walls of specific lengths and made them one color and the vertical a different color so I could snap them into place and then see the places where they overlapped better.

Answer (score 0):

Dissolve those faces that are overlapping, select them and the ones you want them to connect to and press Ctrl + E --> Bridge Edge Loops to fill them.

Comment: I must not have dissolve set up right because when I select the faces and right click and choose dissolve I don't think I am getting the desired result.  https://gyazo.com/7c955f387094fada57b0f5d19da381c1

Comment: press ctrl + L to isolate unjoined objects, ctrl+I to inverse selection, H to hide those, this may help you in dissolving.